# C# ProgressBar Databindings in backgroundworker

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, backgroundworker

I'm no expert in c# but what I'm trying to do is update a progressbar in a Background worker. I'm using the following code:

```
progressBar1.DataBindings.Add("Value", _dm, "Progress", true,
                               DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

This works when executed without background worker, on the GUI thread. The Progress property is a property that updates (using INotifyPropertyChanged)  from the progress of another backgroundworker (where I don't have access to).

How can I make it work so that it updates with the use of a backgroundworker instead of putting it all on the GUI thread?

My code (simplified):

```
class DownloadManager : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private double _progressValue;

    public double Progress
    {
        get { return _progressValue; }
        private set
        {
            if (!value.Equals(_progressValue))
            {
                _progressValue = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Progress"));
            }
        }
    }

    public void Download()
    {
        var downloader = new Downloader();

        downloader.DownloadProgressChanged += (sender, e) 
              => Progress = e.ProgressPercentage;

        downloader.Execute();
    }
}

public partial class MainForm 
{
    private readonly DownloadManager _dm;
    public MainForm() 
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _dm = new DownloadManager();
    }

    private void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           //TRIED HERE ...
           progressBar1.DataBindings.Add("Value", _dm, "Progress", true,
                                          DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
            bwDownload.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }

    private void bwDownload_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        //AND TRIED HERE 
        progressBar1.DataBindings.Add("Value", _dm, "Progress", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);

        //THIS AINT WORKING EITHER
        if (progressBar1.InvokeRequired) {
            progressBar1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() 
                => progressBar1.DataBindings.Add("Value", _dm, "Progress", true,
                                      DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged)));
    }

        _dm.Download();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data bindings should be created in your constructor, as you need to create the binding only once and not every time it's needed:

```
public MainForm() 
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _dm = new DownloadManager();
    progressBar1.DataBindings.Add("Value", _dm, "Progress", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
}
```

Your code is not working because you try to update the UI from non-ui thread. You need need to wrap the code in `Invoke()` call, for example using a proxy property on the Form:

```
public partial class MainForm
{   
    private double _progress;
    public double Progress
    {
        get { return _progress; }
        set
        {
            _progress = value;

            // If not in the UI thread -> wrap the update in an Invoke() call:
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                this.Invoke(new Action(() => progressBar1.Value = (int) _progress), new object[] { });
                return;
            }

            // Else update directly
            progressBar1.Value = (int) value;
        }
    }

    private readonly DownloadManager _dm;
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _dm = new DownloadManager();

        // Bind _db.Progress <-> this.Progress
        DataBindings.Add("Progress", _dm, "Progress", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

GUI elements needs to be updated in the UI thread. You need to use Control.Invoke for updating the controls properties. Mora about this issue: [Data Binding on multi thread application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937743/data-binding-on-multi-thread-application)

Comment: Ain't working either.. I forgot to add that to my simplified code